# Naming convention for a method that enables/disables or activates/deactivates

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

I'm currently working on an objective c project, and have a method that enables/disables OR in another term: activates/deactivates a global HTTP proxy. I was wondering what is the best naming convention for such a method. The method has a BOOL argument to decide which operation to carry out, ie: enable OR disable. It is a style question which is relevant to most programming languages and i've decided I would love the input of this great community on this matter which is bothering me for some reason.

Is this good ? anything better or clearer ?

```
-(BOOL) activate:(BOOL) theActivateFlag;
```

or

```
-(BOOL) enable:(BOOL) theEnableFlag;
```

Will calling [proxyObj activate:NO] OR [proxyObj enable:NO] be understood as deactivating the proxy ?
Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like *form* to reflect *function* in my code

At the top of the file I'd put a

```
#define DISABLED NO
#define ENABLED YES
```

and have my function be

```
- (void)toggleProxyAs:(BOOL)state {
    // assuming enabled is property/instance variable
    enabled = state;
}
```

and use it as

```
[myProxyObj toggleProxyAs:ENABLED];
```

This isn't the standard way of doing things, but for me it is clearer and eliminates the need for separate activators/deactivators.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your much appreciated input and sorry for taking so long. For my needs I actually like this solution very much, because it's very clear that this is a toggle action being carried out and not just a state flag being turned off/on.

Answer (score 2):

Apple makes use of an `enabled` property in their own classes:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
```

That creates the following getter and setter:

```
- (BOOL)isEnabled {
    return enabled;
}

- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag {
    enabled = flag;
}
```

Or you can give your proxy a pair of `activate` and `deactivate` methods or `enable` and `disable` methods.

Comment: +1 I thought about that myself, but as the proxy is (potentially) only a *part* of the class in question, wouldn't that (potentially) be misleading? Still a fine recommendation, that said.

Comment: @middaparka: I was referring to perhaps placing these methods in the proxy class.

Comment: Yup, this is the perfect solution if the proxy class is an instance inside the class the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought (*after thinking about it and changing my mind a few times*)...

```
-(BOOL) enableProxy:(BOOL)shouldEnable;
```

...would make more sense, although I'd be the first to admit that I occasionally wallow in dark pits of naming convention despair (the walls daubed with badly expressed function and method names), so perhaps I'm not best placed to answer this. :-)